# handling the child tags in XSLT when the order of occurance is not specified

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-grouping

I am working on XSLT transformations. I have a source file where I have sometag called  tag.

Consider my source xml to be like this.

```
<ABC>
    <Name>Some Name </Name>
    <ID>Some ID</ID>
    <Address>Some Address</Address>
    <Place>Some Place</Place>
    <ID>Some ID</ID>
    <Name>Some Name </Name>
    <Name>Some Name </Name>     

</ABC>
```

Rules:

```
  ABC is parent Tag which has 4 child tags. Name, ID, Address, Place. 
  These child tags can occur many times and in any ordrer.
  Upon reading the tag , I want to change the name of the tag, and do some processing on the value present in the tag.
  The input XML may have child tags in any order, and many times.
  I want to write a common XSLT which will read the child tags in the order in which they occur, and display them as given under.
```

I want to display the output like this.

```
        <Frame:Name>
                   <text>Some Name</text>
        </Frame:Name>
   <Frame:ID>
                   <text>Some ID</text>
        </Frame:ID>
        <Frame:ADdrress>
                   <text>Some Address</text>
        </Frame:Address>
        <Frame:Place>
                   <text>Some Place</text>
        </Frame:Place>
   <Frame:ID>
                   <text>Some ID</text>
        </Frame:ID>
       <Frame:Name>
                   <text>Some Name</text>
        </Frame:Name>
       <Frame:Name>
                   <text>Some Name</text>
        </Frame:Name>
```

I am completely struck how it can be done.

If the order of occurrence of child elements changes in Source XML it should also reflect in output XML.

Can some one share reviews on it.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your XSLT code? if it looks good then we can modify according to your requirement. We can design a new code but if you post your  code you can know your mistakes

Comment: In the wanted result you have missed one of the last `Name` elements. Please, correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The XSLT way to solve such problems is by using templates. The result is much simpler, shorter and understandable code, usually without any `xsl:choose`, `xsl:when`, `xsl:otherwise`, `xsl:if` or `xsl:for-each`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:Frame="some:undefined namespace">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <t><xsl:apply-templates/></t>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*">
     <xsl:element name="Frame:{name()}" namespace="some:undefined namespace">
       <text><xsl:apply-templates /></text>
     </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<ABC>
    <Name>Some Name </Name>
    <ID>Some ID</ID>
    <Address>Some Address</Address>
    <Place>Some Place</Place>
    <ID>Some ID</ID>
    <Name>Some Name </Name>
    <Name>Some Name </Name>
</ABC>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<t xmlns:Frame="some:undefined namespace">
   <Frame:Name>
      <text>Some Name </text>
   </Frame:Name>
   <Frame:ID>
      <text>Some ID</text>
   </Frame:ID>
   <Frame:Address>
      <text>Some Address</text>
   </Frame:Address>
   <Frame:Place>
      <text>Some Place</text>
   </Frame:Place>
   <Frame:ID>
      <text>Some ID</text>
   </Frame:ID>
   <Frame:Name>
      <text>Some Name </text>
   </Frame:Name>
   <Frame:Name>
      <text>Some Name </text>
   </Frame:Name>
</t>
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. Can i do some manipulations on data of each element. Because, its directly changing the name of the tags right. Please clarify.

Comment: @muzimil: Yes, in the matching template any additional processing can be performed. Please, ask a new question for your new problem. The current problem has a complete solution -- as provided in this answer.

Comment: I want to capture text in each tag and call some other template. Can you please say that if it is possible, then i will post a question to that.

Comment: @muzimil: Please, either edit the question with the new requirement and also show the corresponding wanted result -- or, **better**, ask a new question. Yes, this is possible. XSLT is a Turing-complete language and can be used to implement any algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Based on suggestion from jeevan.

```
  <xsl:template match="ABC" >
    <ABC>
        <xsl:for-each select ="child::*">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="name()='Name'">
            <xsl:element name="Frame:Name">
              <xsl:apply-templates  select="."/>
           </xsl:element>
          </xsl:when>

          <xsl:when test="name()='ID'">
            <Frame:ID>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </Frame:ID>
          </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="name()='Address'">
            <Frame:Address>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </Frame:Address>
          </xsl:when>

          <xsl:when test="name()='Place'">
            <Frame:Place>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </Frame:Place>
          </xsl:when>
     </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: You may be interested to see a solution that is three times shorter :)

Comment: Horrible code. Never use xsl:choose to switch on element name. This is what template rules are for.